# Exporting pdf with mathematical eqns and symbols

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, wiris

Hiii guys, I am trying to build a webpage which exports the html content to a pdf file using tcpdf. I am getting the pdf file but the problem is I'm using tinymce along with wiris editor plugin for math equations, I can't get the math equations in the exported pdf file. Can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Comment: "*..Can anyone provide me a solution for this?*" So, You wanted us to assume your problem & provide solution? Right?

Comment: @NanaPartykar .Probably Yes..Tinymce and wiris is just linked in the php file.Whether you want me to show the full code?